# Bottom border on nested ul/li not entire width

Tags: css, html-lists, border

**Fixed it!** I have added a negative left margin to the gRow class equal to the width of the surrounding container (in my case 744px). It seems to work both in Chrome and IE. It doesn't work in my fiddle though :-?

I have an unordered list depicting a tree-like structure. Each li contains a div element with class="gRow". This div contains other divs with "cells" in a grid. I would like to add a border-bottom on each gRow (or li?) maintaining the padding-left on the li but at the same time having the border-bottom to be the same width for all li/gRows (the entire width of the container).

I'm adding new levels dynamically using Ajax and I don't know the depth of the structure.

This is how far I have gotten:

[image]

My css is like this

```
ul {margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none;}
li { padding-left: 16px;}
.gRow { border-bottom: 1px #CCD9E0 solid;height: 20px; margin-left: -744px;}
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kJQeq/

Hope you can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a negative left margin to the gRow class equal to the width of the surrounding container (in my case 744px). It seems to work both in Chrome and IE. It doesn't work in my fiddle though :-?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margin to 0 on the li as well.

```
ul {margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none;}
li { margin: 0; padding-left: 16px;}
.gRow { border-bottom: 1px #CCD9E0 solid;height: 20px; }
```

Comment: And if you want a space between the left border, and the list items, add left padding to the ul